# Entity data model wizard disappears while adding host name

Tags: entity-framework-6, npgsql

I am having issue while trying to create an entity data model from postgresql database.

The issue is while trying to add the host name, the wizard disappears on typing the first letter itself.

Someone please help on this issue; really stuck at this issue

Comment: Github issue: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1445, will try to take a look soon.

Comment: @ShayRojansky: Thank you for responding. Mine crashes in both Entity Data Model wizard as well as in the server explorer. The postgresql data provider is showing only in the server explorer not in the wizard.

I am using EntityFramework 6.0.0 and Npgsql 2.2.7 along with EntityFramework6.Npgsql. Thx

Comment: Npgsql 2.2.7 is extremely old and the DDEX support has changed a lot - I can't really help you with such an old version... Have you tried the new 3.2 release with a brand-new VSIX (http://www.npgsql.org/doc/ddex.html)? There are some issues currently with the EF wizard, but Server Explorer seems to work very well.